# Binding to a specific CSS transition

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

Hovering the mouse  over an element flips it. I would like a JavaScript function to run when the transition started when the user mouses-off the element, completes.

i.e. I would like some JavaScript to run when the element returns to its natural state (un-flipped, in this case) when the user is no longer hovering over it.

I have tried to bind to the `webkitTransitionEnd` event, but this fires when the transition for hovering completes as well as when the transition for mouse-off completes. How can I distinguish between these two transitions?

My CSS looks like this:

```
.back {
position: absolute;
z-index: 800;
-webkit-transition: z-index 0s linear .25s, -webkit-transform .5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: z-index 0s linear .25s, -moz-transform .5s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
-moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.searchResult:hover .back {
position: absolute;
z-index: 900;
-webkit-transition: z-index 0s linear .25s, -webkit-transform .5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: z-index 0s linear .25s, -moz-transform .5s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
-moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

My JavaScript looks something like this (unsuitable because fires on completion of both mouse over and mouse-off transitions (i.e. flip and un-flip)):

```
el.find('.back').bind("webkitTransitionEnd", function (e) { /* do stuff */ });
```

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful, but I found http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/06/25/timed-notifications-with-css-animations/ today. If you can somehow bind an event to the runProgress 100% parameter it should be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried mouseover and mouseout.

Comment: I assume those would fire when a CSS transition *begins*

Comment: Have you considered jQuery animations? In this case, it may be helpful because they're all-javascript and have handy callbacks.

Comment: Hi Camilo. I have considered JQuery callbacks, but I wish to use CSS3 transitions because of their improved performance on modern browsers. Correct me if this is a wrong assumption.

Comment: @Ben you are right, they are faster, but more particularly on machines with a modern video card. On old machines, the speed is still of a software-based implementation. Also note that webkit transitions are not cross-browser while jQuery is, and on Google Chrome for example, javascript is fast. But if it's something really big or fullscreen, I'd too use CSS3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think (I have yet to perform more than 2 minutes worth of testing) I have solved this issue.

The solution is to add a conditional in the javascript based upon a known CSS property of the  event `target` element. In my case I know the z-index is different in the flipped and non-flipped states, and using this in my javascript appears to solve the issue.

The conditional looks like this:

```
 if(e.originalEvent.propertyName === '-webkit-transform' && 
    $(e.originalEvent.target).css('z-index') === '800') { 

   /*we know we are at the end of the correct transition*/ 

 }
```

My test browser is very modern however (at the time of writing): Chrome 22.0.1186.0 canary.

Answer (score 0):

The event listener actually fires multiple times, once for each property. You can access the property name with event.propertyName. Putting it all together...

```
element.addEventListener("webkitTransitionEnd", function(e){
    if(e.propertyName == "width") {
        doSomething();
    }
}, false);
```

or in jQuery

```
   $(element).on("webkitTransitionEnd", function(e){
        if(e.originalEvent.propertyName == "width") {
            doSomething();
        }
    });
```

Comment: In this case the propertyName is -webkit-transform for both transitions and so I an unable to differentiate between the transitions in my JavaScript based on this. Please see my answer for my latest attempt at a solution.